# How do I safely write a test and test-and-set (TATAS) spinlock with C++11 for x86(-64)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm currently working on a Spinlock class and trying to make it as reasonable as possible, mostly based on advice here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/implementing-scalable-atomic-locks-for-multi-core-intel-em64t-and-ia32-architectures

The work-in-progress looks like this:

```
class Spinlock
{
public:
    Spinlock() : m_lock(false) {}

    void lock()
    {
        // heavy test here for the usual uncontested case
        bool exp = false;
        if (!m_lock.compare_exchange_weak(exp, true, std::memory_order_acquire))
        {
            int failCount = 0;
            for (;;)
            {
                // processor spin loop hint
                _mm_pause();

                // spin on mov instead of lock instruction
                if (!m_lock.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
                {
                    // heavy test now that we suspect success
                    exp = false;
                    if (m_lock.compare_exchange_weak(exp, true, std::memory_order_acquire))
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                // backoff (potentially make exponential later)
                if (++failCount == SOME_VALUE)
                {
                    // Yield somehow.
                    failCount = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void unlock()
    {
        m_lock.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
    }

    std::atomic_bool m_lock;
};
```

However, it seems like having that relaxed read in there can theoretically allow generated code to do unexpected things like create deadlocks: http://joeduffyblog.com/2009/02/23/the-magical-dueling-deadlocking-spin-locks/

This code shouldn't deadlock in the same way as the linked example because the outer acquire should keep the relaxed load from drifting behind, but I don't really have a handle on all the code transformations that could exist. What memory orders and/or fences do I need to keep this code safe without losing performance? Is it possible for a backoff implementation to occur significantly more or less frequently (> a few loops) than intended because the surrounding memory orders are too relaxed?

On a related note, why are spinlock examples around the web using acquire/release memory order for spinlocks instead of sequentially consistent? I found a comment saying that allowing a spinlock release to cross a later spinlock acquire could lead to problems: http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/#IDComment721195810

Answer (score 1):

> This code shouldn't deadlock in the same way as the linked example because the outer acquire should keep the relaxed load from drifting behind, but I don't really have a handle on all the code transformations that could exist.

Acquire operation guarantees that subsequent reads will not be reordered prior to the acquire operation by both compiler and the CPU.

> What memory orders and/or fences do I need to keep this code safe without losing performance?

You do not need any extra synchronization here, your code does the right thing.

> why are spinlock examples around the web using acquire/release memory order for spinlocks instead of sequentially consistent?

Because acquire/release semantics are enough to implement a mutex. On some architecture sequential consistency operations are more expensive than acquire/release.

I cannot recommend enough watching [atomic<> Weapons: The C++ Memory Model and Modern Hardware](http://herbsutter.com/2013/02/11/atomic-weapons-the-c-memory-model-and-modern-hardware/), it covers this subject in great detail.

Comment: At around 44:35 of the atomic weapons talk, Herb mentions that deadlocks could occur by not using SC acquire & release. I think what he's getting at is that if you have lock A, and the code for grabbing lock B is reordered before unlock A for one thread, and another thread has the opposite situation, then the threads could grab both locks, and try to grab each others' before releasing them.

Comment: What is "SC acquire & release" please?

Comment: An example:

Thread 1 (as written): Lock A, Unlock A, Lock B, Unlock B
Thread 2 (as written): Lock B, Unlock B, Lock A, Unlock A
Thread 1 (no-SC potential): Lock A, Lock B, Unlock A, Unlock B
Thread 2 (no-SC potential): Lock B, Lock A, Unlock B, Unlock A

Here if A and B are locked at the same time, the threads will be stuck going for each others' locks.

Comment: @JPark Your deadlock scenario is due to incorrect locking order. It has nothing to do with atomics.

Comment: The talk says the difference between plain acquire/release and a sequentially consistent (SC) acquire/release is that with SC, a release and an acquire cannot pass each other and overlap.

Comment: @JPark There is no such thing as "_a sequentially consistent (SC) acquire/release_". You seem to be confusing memory orderings, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

Comment: load(memory_order_seq_cst) is an SC acquire, store(memory_order_seq_cst) is an SC release.

Comment: @JPark Nope, those are sequentially consistent ordering operations. Acquire and releases orderings are weaker than sequentially consistent one.